# bazel add prefix to directory file

Tags: c++, bazel

```
└── my-project
    ├── c++
    │   ├─ include
    │   │   └── orc
    │   │         └── include   
    │   │              ├── a.h
    │   │              └── b.h
    │   └── src
    │         ├── c.h
    │         ├── d.h
    │         └── io
    │             └── f.h
    ├── WORKSPACE
    └── BUILD
```

in "a.h",can see '#include "orc/b.h"'

in "c.h",can see '#include "io/f.h"'

in "f.h",can see '#include "d.h"'

i don't wanna change the file, how can organiz they by bazel

Comment: I'm curious what build system you currently use where you can have 2 levels of "include" directories, with directories in between that you keep, and have c++ code that pretends neither include directory exists.  bazel can strip a single prefix, via skip_include_prefix="c++/include", but you must remove the include directory under orc (putting .h directly under orc), or add "include" to your #include directive in cpp source file (_#include "orc/include/b.h"_)

Answer (score 1):

`#include "orc/b.h"` won't work. Such a path doesn't exist in your project. You have to change the structure of your project or change it in the code.

`#include "io/f.h"` from `c.h` should work without any changes.

`#include "d.h"` works after you add `my-project/c++/src` to the include paths.

Comment: thanks. finally i decide to change the file contents.